# Is there any potential security concerns if dev tools for chrome are enabled across organisation?

Tags: security, google-chrome-devtools

Im looking to see if there would be any security concerns if dev tools for chrome are enabled. i did a bit of research looking into what features the dev tools provide as well as looking online if i can find anything that could be potentially malicious. I just want confirmation that it is 100% safe, after all its better to be safe than sorry.

If there are threats, how would you also counteract it?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?  What are the use cases?

Comment: Should be flagged and moved to security.SE surely?

Comment: im looking to run some automation script for the general users for the organisation and need devtools to be enabled. Security in my organisation is open to enabling but would also like to know any potential risk.

Comment: I think my answer covers it then - there are occasionally some CVEs, but very few compared to Chrome itself, so the increase in attack surface is small.  Can it not be enabled on a per-user basis?

Comment: Thanks for the information, its hard to manage per-user basis. Looking at CVE web page, am i right to say latest versions of chrome are much more resilient to attacks of any form? Do you have any idea if this also applies to chromium

Comment: Yes and no - over time you would expect there to be less vulnerabilities, but also older software has longer for attacks to be developed and exploited

Answer (score 2):

I can see ways you could an internal user could use dev tools to cause issues, such as using request blocking to ensure tracking scripts aren't downloaded, but nothing that should become major - remember it is a client-side application and your server should handle any malformed requests and only return what it should return.

As for potential attack surface; there are occasionally CVEs against dev tools, such as https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-6112/ but maybe you could just monitor the vulnerability list at https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1224/product_id-15031/opbyp-1/Google-Chrome.html and disable it if anything severe does come up?